# Create a webpage that returns xml

Tags: xml, html

here is my problem.

I need to create a webpage (or whatever it is) like this:
https://secure.motogp.com//en/video/demand/meta/206769

As you can see, it does not end with .xml but returns and xml file (it seems at least).

I have no idea how to achieve this.
Any idea? Thanks

Comment: This site is for professional programmers or programming enthusiasts. It seems you don't fall in this group. Maybe you want to get some tutorial or training instead.

Comment: Hi Thomas, I'm sorry to annoy you. I have some c# knowledge, and I run a website myself. I'm no Java/Php expert at all.
I'm mainly an artist, so that's why I'm asking for tips here...Your comment makes you look like you fall in the group "angry children"

Comment: Look at the answer. Does it solve your problem? No. Certainly not. Because you're missing all the necessary details like programming language, OS and the web server you're using. Also, it does not show any research effort. What have you tried? Have you renamed it to `.xml`? How are we supposed to help you if we have absolutely no idea of what you're doing?

Comment: Yes it solved it :D Cheers

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You use mod_rewrite to hide the file extension.

Or you use mod_alias to hide the file extension.

Or you generate the XML from a server side process using any MVC framework with a routing system in it.

Or you set DirectoryIndex to include `foo.xml` and call the file that.

Or … or … or …

Comment: Thanks very much Quentin, mod_rewrite worked perfectly!

Here is what I added to .htaccess in case some noob like me needs it...

`Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.xml [NC,L]`